# Filtering of array elements by another array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here a simple example

```
import numpy as np
x=np.random.rand(5,5)
k,p = np.where(x>0.5)
```

k and p are arrays of indices

Now I have a list of rows which should be considered  m=[0,2,4], so I need to find all entries of k which are in the list m.

I came up with a very simple but horrible inefficient solution

```
d = np.array([ (a,b) for a,b in zip(k,p) if a in m])
```

The solution works, but very slow. I’m looking for a better and more efficient one. I need to do a few millions of such operations with dynamically adjusted m, so efficiency of an algorithm is really a critical question.

Comment: @U9-Forward as it’s stated in the text, m is just a list. Something like m=[0,2,4]. Example is really simple. In reality it is x is 5000x5000 and len(m) is about a few thousand

Comment: Sorry, i miss that part, :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the below is faster:

```
d=np.dstack((k,p))[0]
print(d[np.isin(d[:,0],m)])
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more. Your solution seems work also well, but it isn’t clear why is it better than Sharu’s solution

Comment: @rth I think it is cleaner, because you just create an array with the `zip` between `k` and `p`, then simply get the rows where the first element is in `m` list.

Comment: Wait, but in this case it should be d[:,0]

Comment: Well I have to admit your solution is the best

Comment: @rth Happy to help, :-), 

Comment: I found that construction array( list( zip( ) ) ) is really slow, even for precomputations. It took almost 5 minutes at the script start, so I wasn’t happy. It seems np.dstack()[0] do the same job 20 times faster. Could please update the answer, so the fastest method will be documented? Thank you!

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [isin()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to get a boolean mask which you can use to index `k`.

```python
>>> x=np.random.rand(3,3)
>>> x
array([[0.74043564, 0.48328081, 0.82396324],
       [0.40693944, 0.24951958, 0.18043229],
       [0.46623863, 0.53559775, 0.98956277]])
>>> k, p = np.where(x > 0.5)
>>> p
array([0, 2, 1, 2])
>>> k
array([0, 0, 2, 2])
>>> m
array([0, 1])  
>>> np.isin(k, m)
array([ True,  True, False, False])
>>> k[np.isin(k, m)]
array([0, 0])
```

Comment: I see. 'isin' was added in numpy 1.13. The equivalent in 1.12 would be [in1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) I assume. You could try that if you're limited to versioning on your system. 

edit: I will leave this comment here in case someone else happens to be curious as to why isin wouldn't work.

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([0, 2, 4])
k, p = np.where(x[m, :] > 0.5)
k = m[k]
print(zip(k, p))
```

This only considers the interesting rows (and then zips them to 2d indices).

Comment: elegant solution, but unfortunately doesn’t work in this way. The k and p are precalulated ones before filtering by different m. Run comparison in reduced but still huge array will be even slower.

Comment: You mean you get `k` and `p` using a different method, and just want to filter `k` using `m` regardless of `x`?

Comment: X is a big but static matrix. There is no reason to scan it more than once to find k and p. I checked your algorithm, it seems it is much slower than my.