# How to filter a numpy array of points by another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

how can I filter a numpy array a, by the elements of a numpy array b so that I get all the points in a that are not in b.

````
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]])
b = np.array([[1,2],[1,3]])
c = np.array([ d for d in a if d not in b])
print(c)

# acutall outcome
# []
# desired outcome
# np.array([[1,4]])```
````

Comment: did you try the `numpy isin` function ? You have more infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928113/filtering-of-array-elements-by-another-array-in-numpy)

Comment: no desired outcome is a numpy array equivalent to np.array([[1,4]])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900165/14463396 I've found this answer for explaining the issue.  If you had everything as a list OPs answer would work, but arrays work differently.

Comment: Thanks, I have really learned something! I'd have done the same mistake. Not intuitive at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably will not be the most efficient (though it turns out to be faster than the other approaches presented here for this input -- see below), but one thing you can do is convert `a` and `b` to Python lists and then take their set difference:

```
# Method 1
tmp_1 = [tuple(i) for i in a]    # -> [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
tmp_2 = [tuple(i) for i in b]    # -> [(1, 2), (1, 3)]

c = np.array(list(set(tmp_1).difference(tmp_2)))
```

As noted by @EmiOB, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899920/numpy-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous/28900165#28900165) offers some insights into why `[ d for d in a if d not in b ]` in your question does not work. Drawing from that post, you can use

```
# Method 2
c = np.array([d for d in a if all(any(d != i) for i in b)])
```

**Remarks**

---

[The implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3544fae2859d8ecac378b9ddc8f909c69455a831/numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c) of `array_contains(PyArrayObject *self, PyObject *el)` (in C) says that calling `array_contains(self, el)` (in C) is equivalent to

```
(self == el).any()
```

in Python,
where `self` is a pointer to an array and `el` is a pointer to a Python object.

In other words:

1. if `arr` is a numpy array and `obj` is some arbitrary Python object, then

```
obj in arr
```

is the same as

```
(arr == obj).any()
```

2. if `arr` is a typical Python container such as a list, tuple, dictionary, and so on, then

```
obj in arr
```

is the same as

```
any(obj is _ or obj == _ for _ in arr)
```

(see [membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)).

All of which is to say, the meaning of `obj in arr` is different depending on the type of `arr`.

This explains why the logical comprehension that you proposed `[d for d in a if d not in b]` does not have the desired effect.

This can be confusing because it is tempting to reason that since a numpy array is a sequence (though not a standard Python one), test membership semantics should be the same. This is not the case.

Example:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]])
print((a == [1,2]).any())          # same as [1, 2] in a
# outputs True
```

**Timings**

---

For your input, I found my approach to be the fastest, followed by Method 2 obtained from the post @EmiOB suggested, followed by @DanielF's approach. I would not be surprised if changing the input size changes the ordering of the timings so take them with a grain of salt.

```
# Method 1
5.96 µs ± 8.92 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
# Method 2
6.45 µs ± 27.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
# @DanielF's answer
16.5 µs ± 276 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing row-wise like this I tend to use @Jaime's recipe for converting to a void view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/4427777) :

```
vview = lambda a:np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))

a[~np.isin(vview(a), vview(b)).squeeze()]
Out[]: array([[1, 4]])
```

This avoids the slow `for` loops of the other answers and doesn't create any intermediate data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
c = np.array([a_elem for a_elem in a if all(any(a_elem != b_elem) for b_elem in b)])
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 4]])
```

**Explanation:**

We loop for a sublist `a_elem` from `a` and check for all sublists from `b`. `any(a_elem != b_elem)` returns `True` if any value from `a_elem` is not equal to `b_elem`. `all(any(a_elem != b_elem) for b_elem in b)` returns True if all sublists are unequal.

**Eg:**

We take `[1,2]` from `a` check if **any** of its elements are unequal to `[1,2]`, `[1,3]` from `b` one by one. So, it'll be `False` for `[1,2]` and `True` for `[1,3]`. This creates a list `[False, True]`

Next, we take `[1,3]` from `a`. It'll return `True` for `[1,2]` and `False` for `[1,3]`. This creates another list `[True, False]`.

Lastly, we take `[1,4]` from `a`. It'll return `True` for both `[1,2]` and `[1,3]`. This creates a list `[True, True]`

Now, when we run `all()` it returns `True` when both values are `True` in the above lists. Hence, we add `[1,4]` to our array.